# Cannot get any sound driver to work for Samplitude

Tags: vst

I cannot get any sound in the magix samplitude and cannot record with any of my Best Service Era VSTs because the sampler is claiming that it does not support WASAPI. "The audio engine (shared mode) or audio endpoint device (exclusive mode) does not support the specified format." is the message it gives off. WASAPI is what I have had the best luck with over ASIO in every other sound program. The sampler will not run anything off of ASIO or any other type of driver. If anyone can help me through this problem I would really appreciate it. I am trying to hook it up to a Focusrite USB WASAPI driver. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was choosing the wrong MIDI settings when I linked it to independence to have audio and MIDI on one track. It was the first option rather than the second that was used in the tutorial video, which worked with my Focusrite ASIO driver.